# How to search for *only* methods in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to have a way to search for methods in a class, only methods, not class member variables, is there a way to do that?.

Comment: Are you trying to do this globally or are you in the class you want to search?

Comment: Only in the class I'm currently in.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik there is not a dedicated way of doing this, but you can use the find action and search on a regex. E.g. something like: `[ ][a-zA-Z]{2,}\(`

[image]

With `cmd+G` you can navigate to the next occurrence. You can easily tweak the regex to search for public methods only if you like.

Alternatively you can press `cmd+F12` to open the "File structure". (you can look it up in the keymap if you want to know the keyboard shortcut for other OS).

You will get more or less the same information when you write "this." and press the shortkey for autocompletion.

Tip: if you want to know if something is available you can always press shift twice and type what you are looking for. Check the "actions" section to see the available actions. Or press the `cmd+shift+A` to search for actions and options instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Structural search](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html). For java there is a pre-defined template for class methods exists (**All methods of the class**):
[image]